# Login history for community user

Tags: force.com

logins are not recorded in login history for community user..Where we need to check the history.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**For specific user**, go to user detail page and see Login History Related list. You will get every information there. (IP address, location, time, username, etc)

If you want to **check complete login history of org**, you can go by Setup >> Login History.
From there you can download the history of recent 20000 logins or last six month login.

**For case of Community** : Login history only generate when a user login using via community login page with the help of Username and password.
It won't generate when login by `Managae External User` button at Contact detail page.

[image: Login History at User Detail page]

[image: Setup >> login history]